# Is there a way to use Spring SpEL inside a method to get a .properties value?

Tags: spring-el

I have a scheduled task class with @Component annotation.  I have this successfully pulling data from the .properties file for the delay time, but I'd like to use that same value later INSIDE the method.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${mypropvalue}")
public void doScheduledTask () throws IOException
    {
     // do some stuff

    log.info("The doScheduledTask finished at {} ", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    log.info("The next task will run in {} ms", @Value("${mypropvalue}"));
    }
```

The @Value on the last line has a compile error saying "Annotations are not allowed here".  How can I get that value again from inside the method?  And since I am using @Scheduled, I cannot pass in that @Value as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it as a field

```
@Value("${mypropvalue}
private long fixedDelay
```

then

```
   this.fixedDelay
```

within your method.

Comment: Yea, I guess that works.  I thought I was hitting a roadblock since it complained when trying to add inside a method with @Scheduled on it, but making it a member variable works all thru the class.

Comment: If you look inside the `@Value` code, you will see it's only allowed on fields, methods, method parameters and other annotations.